# External SSD partition map damaged, can't format (69773/found zeroed-out block/69623)

Tags: disk-utility, partition, ssd, external-disk, disk-format

So my external SSD (1TB Samsung 970 evo plus in an Orico TB3 housing) died. I unmounted it but probably didn't wait long enough and unplugged the drive before completing the unmounting procedure. So the partition map got damaged and I couldn't mount it. I managed to save all data on it with Easeus, but I'm unable to format it. In Disk Utility it only sees the container.

Things I tried:

Disk Utility: I tried first aid and formatting, they failed (for formatting: 69623), both in normal mode and recovery mode.

Terminal: I tried to force unmount (diskutil unmountDisk force /dev/disk0), it failed.

Single user: I tried unmounting and it says: not currently mounted.

Formatting on a Windows machine: it doesn't even recognize it at all.

Could I theoretically try to format the disk in terminal without ejecting it first?

Weird thing is that in single user mode, when the disk is plugged in, there's a disk0, disk0s1, disk0s2 which I think is this external drive (the internal is supposed to be disk1 with more partitions), but when unplug it and replug it, there's still a disk0, disk0s1, disk0s2, AND a disk2 and a disk3. Maybe the disk0 is the one that I should try to unmount because it's stuck?

diskutil info says:

````
   Device Node:               /dev/disk0
   Whole:                     Yes
   Part of Whole:             disk0
   Device / Media Name:       Samsung SSD 970 EVO Plus 1TB

   Volume Name:               Not applicable (no file system)
   Mounted:                   Not applicable (no file system)
   File System:               None

   Content (IOContent):       GUID_partition_scheme
   OS Can Be Installed:       No
   Media Type:                Általános
   Protocol:                  PCI-Express
   SMART Status:              Verified

   Disk Size:                 1.0 TB (1000204886016 Bytes) (exactly 1953525168 512-Byte-Units)
   Device Block Size:         512 Bytes

   Media OS Use Only:         No
   Media Read-Only:           No
   Volume Read-Only:          Not applicable (no file system)

   Device Location:           External
   Removable Media:           Fixed

   Solid State:               Yes
   Virtual:                   No
   Hardware AES Support:      No```


I'm not a computer scientist or anything, all I "know" is from reading stuff on google.

Any help appreciated!
````

Comment: Erase the drive, not a volume or the container.  Remove the container and let Disk Utility recreate it.  View >> Show All Devices, select the top level, and choose 'Erase'.

Comment: A damaged partition map can cause various issues with your external SSD, including the inability to format it. If you're encountering error codes 69773 or 69623, It indicates a corrupted partition table that needs to be repaired or there may be some bad sectors on the drive. You can use `Disk Management` built-in tool that allows you to manage and repair disk partitions. You can also use third-party partition repair tools like EaseUS Partition Master https://www.easeus.com/computer-instruction/format-external-disk-using-scheme-guide-partition-map.html which repair partition table errors.